# How to initialize page every time navigating to it (UWP C#)?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I'm using pivot in UWP C#, when every PivotItem is a page. Every press on PivotItem go to a switch case and choose which Page (Frame) to load. My problem is that, first time everything working ok, but if I leave one page and press again to that pivot weird things happening. I need that the page will be initialized exactly the same every time I opening it

The Pivot in Xaml:

```
<Pivot x:Name="XmlConfigPivot" SelectionChanged="XmlConfigPivot_SelectionChanged">
        <PivotItem Header="Stub_Tab">
            <Frame/>
        </PivotItem>
        <PivotItem Header="Layout">
            <Frame/>
        </PivotItem>
 </Pivot>
```

CS code when pressing PivotItem:

```
private void XmlConfigPivot_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
        PivotItem item = ((sender as Pivot).SelectedItem) as PivotItem;
        string header = item.Header.ToString();
        Frame frame = item.Content as Frame;
        switch (header)
        {
            case "Layout": frame?.Navigate(typeof(LayoutTab)); break;
            case "Stub_tab": frame?.Navigate(typeof(StubTab)); break;
        }
}
```

The "LayoutTab" is a XAML+CS page that do things in it's initialization, It's not really relevant what it do, but it's need to be clean slate every time I'm opening it.

Layout just for example (the real logic is too complicated to put here):

```
public sealed partial class LayoutTab : Page
{
    public ObservableCollection<Sensor> sensorsCollection = new ObservableCollection<Sensor>();
    public ObservableCollection<Axis> axisesCollection = new ObservableCollection<Axis>();
    int selectedSensor = -1;

    static bool isInitializes = false;

    public LayoutTab()
    {
        InitData();
        InitializeComponent();
        isInitializes = true;
    }
}
```

My problem is every time i get into the page it is remembering stuff from last visit, like the variable "sensorsCollection", and I need it to be clean slate.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you check if adding `NavigationCacheMode="Disabled"` in your LayoutTab XAML `<Page>` class solves your problem?

Comment: Hi, I think it did work, for now at least I get the results I needed, Thanks!

Comment: @Doedoe, Your solution works, you could post it as an answer for this question.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that your `LayoutTab` page is set to be cached, so that every navigation to the same page will load its previous properties

My suggestion would be set `NavigationCacheMode` in your page to `disabled` either:

> Programmaticaly:

```
public LayoutTab()
{
    InitData();
    InitializeComponent();
    isInitializes = true;
    NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Disabled
}
```

> or Inside XAML:

```
<Page ...
      NavigationCacheMode="Disabled"
/>
```

( your `NavigationCacheMode` might be set to either "Required" or "Enabled" since the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.page.navigationcachemode) stated that the default cache mode is `disabled` )